# Payload Error - Unknown type name 'CustomFieldTranslation' specified in package.xml

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli

I want to deploy / retrieve CustomFieldTranslations for any object to a Sandbox, but receive an error:
Unknown type name 'CustomFieldTranslation' specified in package.xml

I tried to deploy via path, via package.xml and I tried to deploy only the field translation, the fieldtranslation + the custom field and the fieldtranslation + the custom field + the object.

Push / Pull in Scratch Orgs does work.

My sfdx version is: sfdx-cli/7.116.2 darwin-x64 node-v14.17.5

Comment: do you have Translation Workbench enabled on your org ?

Comment: This is a bug reported on https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1161. Since the issue still happens on CLI version 7.116.2 for several users, I have reached out to the concerned Salesforce team for reopening/further investigation. I will share more inputs as I have. Thank you

Comment: @TimN Based on recent comment on github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1161, the issue is fixed in the latest release.Can you please check and confirm.Thanks